# React - useEffect() causes cascading renders when used for declarative state logic

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've been enjoying React Hooks for a while now. They offer the chance to write declarative logic in a very clear and concise manner. For instance, consider this custom `useHistory` hook, which records a history of the values passed in.

```
const useHistory = val => {
  const [history, setHistory] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHistory(history => {
      return [...history, val];
    });
  }, [val]);

  return history;
};
```

It might be used like this to display all the previous values of 'count' over time ([Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-z0s24)):

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const history = useHistory(count);

  const historyStr = history.join(", ");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>History: {historyStr}</div>

      <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>Decrement</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The app runs perfectly. However, it has a hidden flaw. Because `useEffect` hooks are called *after* render, Every time a button is clicked, the app renders twice. 
This is just a toy example; in large applications, complex chains of `useEffect` dependencies can cause cascades of renders, which absolutely tanks performance.

`useEffect` seems to be primarily designed for side effects, and there isn't much in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to indicate whether updating state within `useEffect` hooks is considered acceptable.

That being said, the expressivity that is offered by using the `useEffect` hook to handle state logic (like we see in the `useHistory` example) is very appealing, and (seems to be) impossible to replicate with an alternative solution.

Am I missing something? Is there any way to achieve this sort of pattern, without causing cascading renders?

Answer (score 0):

The function passed to useEffect hooks will be executed for every render cycle. Plus onClick event, useState is called which result a render of the component (1st render) and then useEffect function will be executed which will change the state and then render the component again. So I think that you should avoid update the state for the same event in two functions. In my opinion, useEffect is useful for side effects like sending http requests and not to update state for user's actions.

I suggest as solution:

```
function App() {
  // Not necessary to save count because count = history[history.length - 1]

  const [history, setHistory] = useState([]);

  const historyStr = history.join(", ");
  console.log("render");

  return (

    <div className="App">
      <div>History: {historyStr}</div>

      <button
        onClick={() => setHistory(prev => [...prev, prev[prev.length - 1] - 1 ])}>
        Decrement
        </button>
      <button onClick={() => setHistory(prev => [...prev, prev[prev.length - 1] + 1 ])}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The functionality of the toy app is less important than the core issue. It's clear that implementing something like what you've described here will solve the double render problem, but the advantages of custom hooks and declarative API is lost.

Comment: Effectively, in this example of user's actions handling there is no advantage of using react hooks ! I invite you to read my full answer !

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I see: When you click the button, it changes your state (count) and re-renders your component. After re-rendering, your useEffect, which is following the changes in [val] sees a change in [val] and calls the setHistory inside. That changes your state (history) again and re-renders your component. I think, regardless of using useEffect, you would have to render twice because of your app design: Your first state change triggers another state change. Every state change = component re-render.

Comment: Yep, exactly. I don't know enough about the inner workings of React to know if it would be possible to work otherwise. But your comment does make me realize that it is likely impossible to avoid, even if some new hook could be introduced that takes effect at another point in the component lifecycle.